# Page redirection not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I try to redirect a page by using window.location in js.

The page gets not redirected instead of showing **Cannot GET /reportCaseupload** like that in a blank page

can somebody say what can i do?

Here my code is:

```
temp[8] = "<span  class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'  title=\"Upload Report\"  onclick=\"reportCaseupload(\'" + datum._id + "\')\"></span>";

function reportCaseupload(id) {
    debugger;
    window.location.href ='/reportCaseupload';
}
```

This means when i click a button,the reportCaseupload function will call and it simply wants to redirect my reportcaseUpload.html page thats it.

Comment: Can you help us help you by posting your code?

Comment: kindly go through the above updated code

Comment: which version of angular are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to inject **$location** in your controller

```
 app.controller('rootController', function($scope, $location) 
   { 
     $location.url('http://google.com');  // to redirect specified url  
     $location.path('/app/login');  // to redirect relative path .
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you do not need the **/** in your **window.location.href** statement. You should also likely be ending the href with the .html extension if "reportCaseUpload" is a html file.

It should look like this:

```
window.location.href = "reportCaseUpload.html"; //or just "reportCaseUpload"
```